# Text animation options - animated GIF or Javascript or..?

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

For my recent project I need to add a specific text animation - to achieve the effect of a pen writing some text on canvas.

I would like to hear your thoughts what would be the best way how to do that based on your experience?

Could you point me in the right direction and include some references where I could learn how to do that?

I am currently using Twitter Bootstrap Framework for Frontend.

Comment: Check `canvas`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas

Comment: I would always use animated GIF where possible, as with javascript you are firing events and causing a redraw when you don't necessarily have to. This also reduces the complexity of your javascript, letting the animation take care of itself. That being said, if you want the text to be editable/copyable, you'll have to use some sort of JS solution

Comment: Good point, thanks a lot Abe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://lazylinepainter.info/

This is just the tool you need

Comment: I actually found this tool very helpful for creating quick animations that look like they are hand written.

Comment: The main website is down, but the github is available here: [http://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter](http://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries helping you to animate your content without using canvas (not cross browser...)

http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS

http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/